# Share variable in angular directives

Tags: angularjs

I have few directives like

```
app.directive('navContent', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        content: "="
    },
    templateUrl: '../../' + template + '/regions/nav.html',
}
});


app.directive('headerContent', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        content: "="
    },
    templateUrl: '../../' + template + '/regions/header.html',
}
});
```

all need a template var in templateURL.

I have tried with a function without success

```
var siteID = angular.element('head').data('site-id');
$http.get('/api/sites/' + siteID)
    .success(function(site) {
        var template = site.template;   
       })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
};
```

siteID is in DOM:

```
<head data-site-id="123456">
```

and site.template should return template from Site model

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: any reason why your `site.template` isnt in the scope?

Comment: unreasonable to put `template` as data attribute also, not just `site-id`?

Comment: Not really! What do you think? I dont know how to get the value using timeout

Comment: You'll likely have issues if the `templateUrl` is requested prior to your `$http` call resolving.

Comment: @Artefact please see my answer below using `document.head.dataset.siteId` as this offers a much cleaner solution than an angular service or scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `$rootScope` to share data, as in the answer from @Edward Knowles, is perfectly legal and works great.

However, by putting the data on the `$rootScope` you are putting that data on every other `$scope` in your application. This may not be ideal (variable conflicts, breaks encapsulation, unit tests more brittle, etc).

Another way to share data is to use Angular services/factories. This puts the data into something you can inject into all of your controllers/directives.

```
app.service('SharedData', function() {
  var service = {
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: 'bip'
  };

  return service;

});


app.directive('myDirective', function(SharedData) {
  // do something w/SharedData
});
```

Comment: Using a service is also a poor idea when OP can simply get the value from the DOM, there is NO case where OP will need to set this value.

Comment: @EdwardKnowles good point. I think I was overreacting to the use of `$rootScope` and not thinking about the OP's actual use case. For one data point that will never change using a service might be overkill. Using a service tends to DRY up the code, but, in this case we're talking about a one liner (to fetch data from the DOM) ... pick your poison :)

Answer (score 1):

You're best option would be setting this variable in the `$rootScope`. This will then be available to all your directives.

**EDIT**: use this instead: `document.head.dataset.siteId`

```
var siteID = angular.element('head').data('site-id');
$http.get('/api/sites/' + siteID).success(function(site) {
  $rootScope.template = site.template;   
  }).error(function(data) {
    console.log('Error: ' + data);
  });
};
```

You can now compile the template into the directive dynamically.

```
app.directive('headerContent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      var linkFn;
      var templateUrl = '../../' + scope.template + '/regions/header.html';

      $http.get(templateUrl).then(function(response) {
        linkFn = $compile(response.data);
        element.html(linkFn(scope));
      });   
    }
  }
});
```

**EDIT**: As mentioned in the comments there are lots of ways of doing this essentially you want to get that `data` value into the compile function. You can use [$rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) which I would not use in production, or a service. However it's unlikely that the data would change so you might even be better of using something like.

```
 .directive('myDirective', function ($http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: true,
            link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                var linkFn;
                var templateUrl = '../../' + document.head.dataset.siteId + '/regions/header.html';
                $http.get(templateUrl).then(function(response) {
                    linkFn = $compile(response.data);
                    element.html(linkFn(scope));
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sharing data between places should be done with services/factories. Attaching data to $rootScope should only be done as a last resort.

Comment: either way my answer still stands, set it however you want, constant, getter/setter, scope. Then using `$compile` on the html and set it to itself.

Comment: Sure, there's also a way you could create a variable and hold it outside of angular entirely. That does not make it correct :)

Comment: I agree w/@MathewBerg ... I was actually typing an alternative answer when he commented. I think using the scopes to share data is ok to a point. I try to avoid doing that w/the `$rootScope`. I generally share data between scopes via the parent/child scope inheritance ... but that is easy to abuse and overtime can become code smell. Angular Services/factories/constants are definitely a better solution in medium/large apps.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but since he is just reading the value from the HTML, he doesn't need a whole new service running getters and setters. I've updated my answer with an alternative simpler solution using the DOM. `document.head.dataset.siteId`.

Comment: This is getting a little bit complicated for what you need. I'll create a new answer.

Comment: in var siteID = angular.element('head').data('site-id'); $http… I get $http is undefined

Comment: Don't use `angular.element('head')`! Please see my other answer below, I've included a working example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript to grab the data attribute from the HTML by using `document.head.dataset.siteId`

Working example ->
http://jsbin.com/cijukinoca/1/edit?html,js,output listen to the network request. It will show `Request URL: http://null.jsbin.com/123456/regions/header.html`

```
app.directive('headerContent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        content: "="
    },
    templateUrl: '../../' + document.head.dataset.siteId + '/regions/header.html',
  }
});
```